# Classes autoload using namespaces for parent and children

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I read several articles about using namespaces in php but I didn't get it yet. I have 3 files:

script.php and dog.php are located in same root folder, abstr. class animals.php is located in cls folder, and dog extends animals.

Sources:
`cls/Animals.php:`

```
namespace cls;
abstract class Animals { .. }
```

`Dog.php` ( no namespace since it's located in root folder ):

```
 class Dog extends Animals {...}
```

`script.php`:

```
function __autoload($cls){
     $file = str_replace('\\',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$cls).".php";
    if(file_exists($file)){
        require_once $file;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("File not found: ".$file);
    }
}

$dog = new Dog("German Shepard");
```

But I get `Not found exception` for class Animals and `$file` is simply `Animals.php` without namespace...

1. Can anyone tell me how to get namespace and include it in path for `__autoload` function?
2. Or is it better to use same namespace for parent and child?
3. And as I understood right namespace = file location?

Answer (score 0):

If Dog is not in 'cls' namespace you have to write full qualified name for Animals class:

```
class Dog extends \cls\Animals { ... }
```